# WKWebView inside a tableView Cell dynamic height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView inside a UITableViewCell, which loads an HTML string (I have embedded a tweet).

I have tried all types of solutions on Stack Overflow, but they didn't work for me. Here is an example of something I tried:

```
class DetailWebCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var detailWebView: WKWebView!

    @IBOutlet weak var containerHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        detailWebView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false

    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        self.detailWebView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState", completionHandler: { (complete, error) in
            if complete != nil {
                self.detailWebView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight", completionHandler: { (height, error) in
                    self.containerHeight.constant = height as! CGFloat
                })
            }

            })
    }


}
```

But the cell's height remains the same

[image]

I want the height of the WKWebview to be the same height as the tableView Cell's

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
self.containerHeight.constant = detailWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height
```

Comment: Although the code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the problem is and **how** the code helps.

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani The cell gets even smaller than in the photo, and you can only see a little bit of the embedded tweet.

Comment: @H.Osjir Try to call `layoutIfNeeded()` after you set `self.containerHeight.constant`.

Comment: It stays the same, and I don't think that thats how you do it

Comment: @H.Osjir I think you need to replace **WKWebView** with **UITextView** because webview take more time to load so replace it and set HTML Data in UITextView.

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani It has to be a WKWebView

Comment: @H.Osjir  do you have multiple cells , when are you update the containerHeight constraint ?

Comment: I have also tried all the solution but no luck for dynamic height with html text in WKWebview. Any one find solution?